# Can a function access args passed to main()?

Tags: c++, c, program-entry-point, args

Is there a way I could access program's args outside of `main()` without storing references to them?

Program arguments are stored within preserved space of the program, so I see no reason for not being able to access them. Maybe there is something like `const char** get_program_arguments()` and `int get_program_arguments_count()` but I cannot find it...

My problem comes from the fact that I am rewriting a library that is used now in many programs within the company, and I need to access these programs common arguments without changing them. For example I need program name, but I cannot use `::getenv("_")` as they can be executed from various shells. I cannot use GNU extension because this needs to work on Linux, AIX, SunOS using gcc, CC and so on.

Comment: Pass them to the function that needs them?

Comment: I think a common pattern is to have your library initialize with a `init(int argc, char** argv)`.

Comment: If you are asking "is there a Standard Library function that gives this access", the answer is "no".

Comment: *I see no reason for not being able to access them* remember the dangers of global data.

Comment: @NeilButterworth - I think you could write this as an answer if you are sure there is none. That's basically the answer to my question in comparison to the first two that seem to do not bother to read all question.

Comment: @NathanOliver: The clue is "My problem comes from the fact that I am writing a library". If I had a freedom to change programs then I would not bother asking this question on stackoverflow.

Comment: @merlin2011: If I could change programs then I would not bother asking this particular question here.

Comment: "The clue is "My problem comes from the fact that I am writing a library"." - if you are writing a library, then something needs to call that library code. That something can initialise your library by calling a function in your library. Nathan's and merlin's comments describe what your library needs to do if it is to processs command-line parameters.

Comment: There's a difference between "I am writing a library" and "I am making changes to an existing library that's already in use". In the former you can enforce whatever rules you want, .e.g "make sure `init()` is called before calling any of these functions". It isn't clear which state you're in

Comment: @Kevin - fair. I thought the sentence "without storing references to them" was enough and then added explanation of my task. I will rewrite it for clarity, despite accepting answer. Thanks!

Comment: Off: If you wish to pass options to your library without modifing the main program, you can use environment variables or configuration files.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond: köszönöm. That's a great idea. I don't know if this fly through with the team but I like it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some systems do provide access to the argument list, or at least [`argv[0]`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Error-Messages.html#Error-Messages).  But it’s common practice for `main` to [*mutate*](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Using-Getopt.html#Using-Getopt) `argc` and `argv` during option processing, so there is no reliably correct answer as to what a global interface for them should return.

Add to that the general undesirability of global state, and the fact that it harms debugging to have whatever low-level functions attempt to analyze the arguments to a program they might know nothing about, and you end up with *don’t do that*.  It’s not hard to pass arguments (or, better, meaningful flags that result from decoding them) to a library.